# I am trying to convert a flan-t5 pytorch model to GGUF format

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, transform, huggingface-transformers

I have tried to convert the model using the llama.cpp convert.py following the colab note [HERE](https://colab.research.google.com/github/TrelisResearch/gguf-quantization/blob/main/HuggingFace_to_GGUF.ipynb#scrollTo=CmT3xkz0GHJN).

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    device_map='cpu',
    offload_folder='offload',
    cache_dir=cache_dir
)
```

Facing an error at `!python convert.py models/`
Error:

```
Loading model file models/pytorch_model.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/llama.cpp/convert.py", line 1208, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/llama.cpp/convert.py", line 1157, in main
    params = Params.load(model_plus)
  File "/content/llama.cpp/convert.py", line 288, in load
    params = Params.loadHFTransformerJson(model_plus.model, hf_config_path)
  File "/content/llama.cpp/convert.py", line 203, in loadHFTransformerJson
    n_embd           = config["hidden_size"]
KeyError: 'hidden_size'
```

Kindly help me convert the [google/flan-t5-large](https://huggingface.co/google/flan-t5-large) model to GGUF format.